# Split a file into multiple files if it reaches a particular limit?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, strings, file

For each `clientId`, I have a `Collection<Task>` object. I am making file for each `clientId` and for each `clientId` file, I have all their tasks in it separated by new line in it.

Below is my original code:-

```
public class FileProcessor {
  private final String clientId;
  private final Collection<Task> tasks;

  public FileProcessor(String clientId, Collection<Task> tasks) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.tasks = tasks;
  }

  public void generateFile() {
    String fileName = "tasks_info_" + clientId + ".txt";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Task task : tasks) {
      sb.append(task).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))) {
      writer.write(sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Let' say if `clientId` is `123`, then it will create a file called `"tasks_info_123.txt"` with all the tasks in it. Now I have a requirement that **file size of each `clientId` file cannot go more than 50000 bytes**. So now what I have to do is:

- I have to split each `clientId` file into multiple files like this: `"tasks_info_123_0.txt"`, `"tasks_info_123_1.txt"`, `"tasks_info_123_2.txt"`
- As you can see, I have added `"_0"`, `"_1"`, `"_2"` in it.
- So I will keep creating multiple files for each `clientId` until I can fit all the data in it and also making sure each file size is not more than 50000 bytes.
- If we can fit all the data in one file, then I will have only one `clientId` file like this: "tasks_info_123_0.txt"
- Also we should not create a file if collection of task object is empty.

So I got below code but it is not efficient as well seems like so opting for code review to see if there is any better and efficient way?

```
  public void generateFile() {
    int size = 0;
    int index = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Task task : tasks) {
      sb.append(task).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
      size += sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
      if (size > 50000) {
        String fileName = "tasks_info_" + clientId + "_" + index + ".txt";
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))) {
          writer.write(sb.toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        index++;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        size = 0;
      }
    }
    // for cases where we don't reach the limit
    String fileName = "tasks_info_" + clientId + "_" + index + ".txt";
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))) {
      writer.write(sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Note: I don't want to use logger for this, just that I want to try it out on my own.

Comment: You can't determine the file size based on the "already written Strings". UTF-8 uses 1-4 bytes per character (I think). Also, the line separator on *nix is \n, in windows it's \r\n, so there's probably a but between the "add line separator" and the file size check.

Comment: It doesn't have to be exact, just approx calculation should be fine.

Comment: Well, first of all you wrote very clear, even in bold letters, that the requirement is, that a file cannot go more than 50'000 bytes. And second, potentially 400% larger files is very far from 'approximately the same size'.

Comment: yeah what I mean by that was files will be made up of strings so if we can restrict the size of string then file size will be restricted as well.

Comment: You count bytes using `UTF-8`, but write bytes to the file in the default encoding, which might be different..

Comment: @RobAu good point so how can we fix that? And is there any other optimization we can do? Looking at the code, I am repeating writing at two points so not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001562/461499

Comment: Writing to files with a limit on byte size is a common requirement in logging systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to limit *file size*, measured in bytes.
You write *records*, one for each `task`, terminated by `line.separator`.
You are concerned about *performance* (with a limit of just 50 kB on file size - oh well).

- do not encode `char`s more than once (with *2n* (guesstimated: 50) records per file, your average `char` gets encoded n+1 (26) times with the second `generateFile()` presented)
- using "old Java IO", have a `FilterOutputStream` tally bytes
- do not use a buffered `Writer`: it would obscure record boundaries

giving it a try:

```
/** Writes a limited amount of bytes to each of
 *  a succession of files numbered from 0 where necessary.
 *  Buffers liberally. */
static class SequentialFileOutputStream extends java.io.FilterOutputStream {
    final static int MAXBUF = 1<<20;
    final byte[]buffer;
    int pos, index;
    final long limit;
    long left;
    File file;
    String path, name, suffix;
    /** Creates an OutputStream that starts writing
     *  to <code>file</code>, creating numbered files as necessary. */
    public
    SequentialFileOutputStream(File file, boolean append, long limit)
        throws IOException
    {
        super(null);
        File parent = (this.file = file).getParentFile();
        if (null == parent)
            parent = new File(".");
        // checks path, too
        if (parent.getFreeSpace() < limit)
            throw(new java.io.IOException("free < limit"));
        this.limit = left = limit;
        buffer = new byte[(int) Math.min(limit, MAXBUF)];
    }
    /** Closes the current part, if any. */
    void closePart() throws IOException {
        if (null != out) try {
            flush();
        } finally { try {
            out.close();
        } finally {
            out = null;
        }}
    }
    /** Finishes the current part, if any.
     * Prepares a new one as far as necessary. */
    void nextPart() throws IOException {
        closePart();
    }
    /** Ensures <code>out</code> is open and buffer reset. */
    void ensureOpen() throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (null != out)
            return;
        left = limit;
        pos = 0;
        if (null == suffix) {
            path = file.getPath();
            name = file.getName();
            int dot = name.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (0 <= dot) {
                suffix = name.substring(dot);
                path = path.substring(0,
                    path.length() - suffix.length()) + '_';
            } else
                suffix = "";
            out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);
        } else {
            if (null != file) {
                File zero = new File(path + '0' + suffix);
                zero.delete();
                file.renameTo(zero);
                file = null;
            }
            out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(path + ++index + suffix);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        byte[]a = { (byte) b };
        write(a, 0, a.length);
    }
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)
        throws IOException {
        if (len <= 0 || null == b)
            return;
        ensureOpen();
        if (left < len && 0 < pos) {
            flush();
            nextPart();
        }
        if (limit < len)
            out.write(b, off, len);
        else {
            System.arraycopy(b, off, buffer, pos, len);
            pos += len;
            left -= len;
        }
    }
    @Override // closePart()?
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        if (0 < pos) {
            ensureOpen();
            out.write(buffer, 0, pos);
            pos = 0;
        }
        out.flush();
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException { closePart(); }
}
private final String clientId;
private final Collection<Task> tasks;

public FileSplitter(String clientId, Collection<Task> tasks) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.tasks = tasks;
}
/** Kludge to flush an OutputStreamWriter's encoder's buffer */
static class FlushWriter extends java.io.OutputStreamWriter {
    final static Class[]NO_CLASSES = {};
    static java.lang.reflect.Method flushEncoder;
    // further constructors left as an exercise
    public FlushWriter(OutputStream out) { super(out); }
    /** Flushes the encoder's buffer */
    java.io.Writer flushEncoder() {
        try {
            if (null == flushEncoder) {
                final Class<?> osWriter = FlushWriter.class.getSuperclass();
                flushEncoder = osWriter
                    .getDeclaredMethod("flushBuffer", NO_CLASSES);
                flushEncoder.setAccessible(true);
            }
            flushEncoder.invoke(this, (Object[])null);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this;
    }
}

public void generateFile() {
    String fileName = "tasks_info_" + clientId + ".txt",
        lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    try (FlushWriter writer = new FlushWriter(
            new SequentialFileOutputStream(
                new File(new File("."), fileName), false, 9000))) {
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            writer.append(task.toString()).append(lineSeparator);
            writer.flushEncoder();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Task t = new Task() {@Override public String toString() {
                return "I am the most useless task ever";
        }};
    Collection<Task>tasks = new java.util.ArrayList<>(999);
    for (int i = 999 ; 0 < --i ; )
        tasks.add(t);
    new FileSplitter("broke", tasks).generateFile();
}
```

The non-buffered `OutputStreamWriter` didn't suffice, in the end:
Sunsoft's encoder buffers. Trying to keep that from interfering messed things up.

The `generateFile()` from the question seems to have a correctness issue with the way it guesstimates byte count: it extends `sb` *and accumulates* "the length of `byte[]`s gotten from `String` representations of `sb`". It should rather

- *set* the size to said length - or -
- accumulate the "byte length" of the `String` for each `Task`
  which, in combination with instantiating `sb` with an appropriate length, should lead to run time linear in the number of bytes in each file rather than quadratic.

But once you "have the `byte[]`", you might as well collect those.
This seems to call for `java.nio.ByteBuffer` &co:

```
public void generateFile() {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(limit);
    for (Task task : tasks) {
        byte[]taskBytes = task.toString().getBytes(
            java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int taskLen = taskBytes.length+LS_LENGTH;
        if (bb.remaining() < taskLen)
            buffer2file(bb, index++);
        if (limit < taskBytes.length+2*LS_LENGTH) {
            ByteBuffer big = ByteBuffer.allocate(taskLen);
            big.put(taskBytes).put(LINE_SEPARATOR_BYTES);
            buffer2file(big, index++);
        } else
            bb.put(taskBytes).put(LINE_SEPARATOR_BYTES);
    }
    buffer2file(bb, index++);
}

/** Write a numbered client file if <code>bb</code> not empty. */
private void buffer2file(ByteBuffer bb, int i) {
    bb.flip();
    if (bb.hasRemaining()) {
        String fileName = "tasks_info_" + clientId + "_" + i + ".txt";
        try (java.nio.channels.FileChannel
            fc = java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(
                java.nio.file.Paths.get(fileName, NO_STRINGS),
                java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
            fc.write(bb);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    bb.flip();
}
static final String NO_STRINGS[] = {},
    LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
static final byte[]
    LINE_SEPARATOR_BYTES = LINE_SEPARATOR.getBytes();
static final int LS_LENGTH = LINE_SEPARATOR_BYTES.length;
```

Comment: Missed that "_0" was OK - oh well.

Comment: An alternative allowing "the usual encoder buffering" would be to "parse the encoder output for record boundaries" - nothing to look forward to specifying or implementing.